# Formal definition of an outbound vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I've seen many references to the term `outbound vector`, in particular the  `outbound normal vector`;  for example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, given a level set of a function G(**x**), if **x**>0,  the `outbound normal vector` to the surface defined by G(**x**)=0 is, intuitively, the vector perpendicular to the surface and pointing in a north-easterly direction.    Is there a general, formal way to define this intuitive concept?

Comment: If $G(x)=0$ is a Jordan curve, then the complement has two components, one bounded and one unbounded. Then it makes sense to think of the outbound normal, it is that normal, which points to the unbounded component. In general, I'm not aware of such definition.

Comment: I'm only interested in simple closed curves, which appear to be the same as Jordan curves, so this definition is perfect, thanks!